# Obtaining Docker public key.json file

Tags: linux, docker, fedora, fedora-23

I see a `/etc/docker/key.json` on Fedora 23 machine. This file seems like a private key for authentication

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7667

At what time is it generated ( its not present in output of `rpmls docker` ), and how do I obtain a corresponding public key?

My usecase is to enable a non-root user to run `docker ps` command without `sudo` i.e. by the use of public/private keys.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about the `key.json` file, at least as far as I understand your question.

If you want to enable unprivileged users to connect to your Docker daemon using certificates for authentication, you will first need to enable a listening HTTP socket (either binding to `localhost` or to a public address if you to provide access to the daemon from somewhere other than the docker host), and then you will need to configure appropriate SSL certificates as described in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).

You can also provide access to Docker by managing the permissions on the Docker socket (typically `/var/run/docker.sock`).

Note that giving someone access to docker is equivalent to giving them `root` access (because they can always run `docker run -v /etc:/hostetc ...` and then edit your sudoers configuration or `passwd` and `shadow` files, etc.

Comment: What is `key.json` used for? I don't understand that.

Comment: I am not in favor of manipulating `/var/run/docker.sock` to provide access. I understand it is dangerous. However the setup of TLS is too much involved for a casual user. I am looking for some sort of simplification, or atleast a tool that minimizes the effort.